# how to print specific value in dictionary

Tags: python

```
data = [
    {
        'name': 'Instagram',
        'follower_count': 346,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        'follower_count': 215,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    }]
```

how to print follower_count of any one of tthe two given dict

Comment: just select any of the element from the list by data[i] where i represents the index of element and perform a get operation by data[i]['follower_count']

Comment: "how to print follower_count of any one of tthe two given dict" - depends on which dictionary you want to get data from

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of dictionaries, so what you’ll need to do is first index the array before accessing the follower count.

Something like:

```
data[i][“follower_count”]
```

Where `i` is some index in the array.

Comment: and if i want to use random moddule    
one=random.choices(data)                      print([one]["follower_count"])   
i m doing this its not working

Comment: `random.choices` will return a list of `k` random selections. `k` defaults to `1`, so you’d need to access it via `one[0][“followers_count”]`.

If you only want a single item returned it’d make more sense to use `random.choice` and you’ll receive one item which can be accessed using `one[“followers_count`

Comment: By putting `one` inside brackets it adds a dimension to the list, so you don’t want to be doing that

Answer (score 0):

Basically, just select the dict you want (0 if you want the first) and then select the 'follower_count' value like so:

data[0]['follower_count']

Comment: and if i want to use random moddule

Comment: one=random.choices(data)
print([one]["follower_count"])

Comment: i m doing this its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a random choice between 346 and 215 you should import random, the code should look like this if you want to print the 'follower_count' in any of those two dicts:

```
import random

data = [
    {
        'name': 'Instagram',
        'follower_count': 346,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        'follower_count': 215,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    }
]

x = random.randint(0,1)
print(data[x]['follower_count'])
```